# I think its all ok but it's giving some simple mysql syntax error

Tags: php, mysql

I don't think that there should be any error pls check and respond fast.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO users (Name, Price, SaleDonate, Publisher,Author,PrintedPrice,ImageFront,ImageMiddle,ImageBack,SchoolCollage,Course,Class,City,Code,Part,Category,PosterId,PublishingDate,PostingDate)"
    ." VALUES"
    ." ('$name','$price','$saledonate','$publisher','$author','$printedprice','$imagefront','$imagemiddle','$imageback','$schoolcollage','$course','$class','$city','$code','$part','$category','$posterId','$publishingdate','$postingdate';";
```

The error is-

```
Could not enter data: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1
```

The data I am entering does not contain any **"**

Pls help and thanks in advance

Comment: At least you're missing a closing parenthesis

Comment: Also do not use this way to do SQL queries. Use parameters. It will save you from so many problems in the future

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen: you should consider making a post with your suggesting in the comment trail above as it answers the actual post so as to have it marked as such.

Comment: @nyedidikeke No, these questions should be closed as "simple typographical error" so there is no point. Not to mention it has already been answered.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen: noted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the below query :-

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO users (Name, Price, SaleDonate, Publisher,Author,PrintedPrice,ImageFront,ImageMiddle,ImageBack,SchoolCollage,Course,Class,City,Code,Part,Category,PosterId,PublishingDate,PostingDate) VALUES(".$name.",".$price.",".$saledonate.",".$publisher.",".$author.",".$printedprice.",".$imagefront.",".$imagemiddle.",".$imageback.",".$schoolcollage.",".$course.",".$class.",".$city.",".$code.",".$part.",".$category.",".$posterId.",".$publishingdate.",".$postingdate.");";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO users (Name, Price, SaleDonate, Publisher,Author,PrintedPrice,ImageFront,ImageMiddle,ImageBack,SchoolCollage,Course,Class,City,Code,Part,Category,PosterId,PublishingDate,PostingDate) VALUES ('$name','$price','$saledonate','$publisher','$author','$printedprice','$imagefront','$imagemiddle','$imageback','$schoolcollage','$course','$class','$city','$code','$part','$category','$posterId','$publishingdate','$postingdate')";
```

Hope this will help you.